# Intellisense not working in VSCode typescript watch window

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I can't get intellisense in the VSCode typescript watch window.

It works great in the code itself - but when I debug, I want to enjoy it as well.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this feature doesn't exist at this time (November 2017) it's on the wishlist :)